# Python desktop app linked to PHP web app?

Tags: php, python

Well, i do want to make a web app in php, where the user could create an account and log in, then download a desktop app made in python, log in there also with the username and the password from the web app and then run in tray. The purpose of this project is none, i want to do it for fun and practice, but i do have some problems. How i could link a web app to a desktop application? That desktop app should gather information about the user's system, harware memory used (like the windows rating) and then send it to the web app and display it in the user's panel. Any ideas ? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need a protocol in order for the two to communicate; I recommend JSON-RPC. Modules are available for both [PHP](http://jsonrpcphp.org/) and [Python](http://json-rpc.org/wiki/python-json-rpc).

Answer (score 1):

There are a million ways to do this. I suggest you write the local data gathering first, to know the amount and format of the data (and because getting Windows hardware information via Python seems to be the hardest part).

Then write the web page login, to see if you can get HTTPS or have to take care of security yourself. With these constrains it is much easier to make a recommendation.